# how should i avoid the error "list index out of range" when in my loop i have empty cells

Tags: python

i have values in google sheets as

```
0  0  0  0
45 12 1  (empty cell)
```

when I try to fetch 2*4 element it gives an error of list index out of range.
I need to identify if the element is null and if so I need to call another function ?

Comment: Can you share the code?

Comment: `value = row[i] if i < len(row) else another_function()`?  If you parse each row into a dict instead of a list, it's even easier: `value = row.get(col, another_function())`